# Get the maximum of two numbers in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, max

I wanted to get the `max` of two values in update rows in MySQL.  I wrote it initally as which didn't work.

```sql
update
    setup
set
    SetupValue = max(SetupValue - 10000, 0)
where
    SetupCode in (
    'lastProcessedAlertID',
      'lastProcessedArtifactID'
  );
```

I got it working by altering the answer that uses `CASE-WHEN` for [Column value based on maximum of two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57084651/column-value-based-on-maximum-of-two-dates) and used numbers.

```sql
update
    setup
set
    SetupValue = (case when SetupValue - 10000 > 0 then SetupValue - 10000 else 0 end)
where
    SetupCode in (
    'lastProcessedAlertID',
      'lastProcessedArtifactID'
  );
```

But I was wondering if there's a better way of doing it without repeating myself or using non-standard constructs like `SET` variable

Comment: Please provides sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

Are you simply looking for `greatest()`?

```
SetupValue = greatest(SetupValue - 10000, 0)
```

Nothing in your second `update` uses only standard SQL.  The first is using an aggregation function inappropriately, so it is not valid in any database (well, except for SQLite which overloads `max()` with multiple arguments to be equivalent to `greatest()`).